# Regex to allow spaces in alphanumeric

Tags: jquery

I have this here:

```
$("#MyInputBox").keypress(function (e) {
  if (e.charCode != 0) {
    var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$");
    var key = String.fromCharCode(!e.charCode ? e.which : e.charCode);
    if (!regex.test(key)) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

Problem is, it does not allow me to enter a space. I WANT it to allow a space. Everything else works fine (i.e I can enter numbers, letters, dash... but not a space.)

Comment: A space where (anywhere)?

Comment: Anywhere except for the beginning and end of the string, and only 1 space allowed after the previous character (the next should be an alphanumeric char inc dash)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You must escape the backslash before the `s`

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\s]+$");
```

or ommit the constructor:

```
var regex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9\-\s]+$/
```

Comment: According to the comment, you'd want something like `^([a-zA-Z0-9\\-][a-zA-Z0-9\\-\\s])+$`

Comment: The question and code of the question is related to the test of a **single character**, this is a answer to the question not to the comments.

Comment: @Dr.Molle I know - I was just throwing out a thought based on the further info about the larger problem that the OP provided - my comment was fairly poorly worded, so sorry for that, but it wasn't meant as a criticism.